# In Visual C++ 2017: Where in the property pages does it say what Application Types correspond to the projets?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, project

I am trying to recreate a Visual C++ Solution that had about 30 projects so that the general organization will be cleaner.
The original "solution" was in fact a Visual C++ 6 workspace from the turn of the century, migrated into VS 2017.

Some of the projects will be close to being clones of the old ones. 
When I try to create a project, I am asked what Application Type it must be:
Single Document/Multiple document/Dialog based or Multiple top level documents.
I thought I could guess this by looking at the property pages of the existing documents, but I can't seem to find it. Or am I likely to be going in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, we couldn't guess this by looking at the property pages of the existing documents. I suggest that you could check `MainFrm.cpp` in the project source file to distinguish the project from a single document / multiple documents / dialog based or multiple top-level documents.

A multiple documents:the document's frame window can hold multiple child windows.

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CMainFrame, CMDIFrameWndEx)
```

A single document:the document's frame window can hold only one document.

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CMainFrame, CFrameWndEx)
```

dialog based: There is no `MainFrm.cpp` in the source file.

multiple top-level documents:Creates a multiple top-level architecture for your application, where a view class is based on CView.

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CMainFrame, CFrameWndEx)
```

clicks New Frame on the File menu:

[image]

For more details, I suggest you could refer to the [Application Type, MFC Application Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/application-type-mfc-application-wizard?view=vs-2019)